# Use aura:id to group or identify field components?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Most examples I've seen for Lightning form validation assign a common *aura:id* to all field components in the form, and then use *component.find* to return the set of components to validate, as in this common code fragment:

```
var allValid = component.find('someId').reduce(function (validFields, inputCmp) {
    inputCmp.showHelpMessageIfInvalid();
    return validFields && inputCmp.get('v.validity').valid;
}
```

This approach seems to preclude what I'd think would be a typical use of *aura:id* -- to uniquely identify a component so it can be accessed individually. The fact that *component.find* returns either a single element *or* an array suggests that the designers expected both kinds of uses.

What, then, is an appropriate way to be able to do that "bulk" validation, or any other iteration through field components, while still being able to access them individually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
// Array of field aura:id values
var auraIds = ['fieldXyz', 'fieldAbc', ...];

var allValid = auraIds.reduce(function(validFields, auraId) {
    // Find component corresponding to the aura:id
    var inputCmp = component.find(auraId);
    inputCmp.showHelpMessageIfInvalid();
    return validFields && inputCmp.get('v.validity').valid;
});
```

or if in the same function you also want to access them individually:

```
var fieldXyzCmp = component.find('fieldXyz');
var fieldAbcCmp = component.find('fieldAbc');
...

var cmps = [fieldXyzCmp, fieldAbcCmp, ...];

var allValid = cmps.reduce(function(validFields, inputCmp) {
    inputCmp.showHelpMessageIfInvalid();
    return validFields && inputCmp.get('v.validity').valid;
});
```

Comment: That's the approach I was considering... thanks for the validation! The use of a common ID for grouping is so ubiquitous in the tutorials that it seemed odd to go another way. I wonder if it might have been a convenience for the purposes of the tutorials that just turned into a common practice.

Comment: @JeffGarbers And it is not even a safe example as the code will fail when there is only one field or if there are no fields thanks to the crazy semantics of `component.find`.